# thread as class, how to assure data of subclasses being destroyed after?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, pthreads

I wrote a wrapper of pthread / windows native threads which mimics java's threads.

```
class Thread{
public:
  virtual void run()=0;
  void start();
  void join();

  virtual ~Thread(){
   join(); 
  }
};
```

Suppose

```
 class B:public Thread{
  int x;     
  void run(){
    while some condition do soemething on x;
  }
};
```

If an instance of B is destructed before run() returns, the thread will keep accessing x, and this is clearly undesirable. To solve the problem I need to add

```
B::~B(){
 join();
}
```

because Thread::~Thread() is called after B::x is destroyed, so that join would have no effect.

However, if I have class C: public B with some additional data, I still need to define C::~C(){join();}

And so forth, all down the hierarchy

An alternative would be to do

```
template<typename R>
 struct SafeThread:public R,public Thread{
  void run(){
    R::run();
  }
};
```

so that R data (our previous B::x ) would be destroyed after the thread has joined. 
However, still

```
class B{
  virtual void f(){...}
  void run(){ f();}
};


class C:public SafeThread<B>{
  int y;
  void f(){
  ...something on y;
  }

};
```

would still have similar problems. 
Do you think there's any elegant solution for solving the problem of assuring data are destroyed after the run method terminates, without forcing every subclass SC to define SC::~SC(){join();} ?

Comment: as for Nick's code, no, because in that way the base class deconstructor is called after B::x is already gone

Comment: Just for reference, C++ is not Java.  Because Java's GC pretty much lets you start a thread and forget about it, letting it keep itself alive til it's done, Java's thread API can take advantage of that.  You can't.

Comment: Ensuring that the lifetime of all data accessed by a thread exceeds the lifetime of the thread works well, as does never explictly terminating threads at all, (pools or app-lifetime threads). If I don't have to call join() for the rest of my life, it'll still be a million years too soon.

Comment: You should consider using the *other* Java option: implementing `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread`. That is a much better design, a *thread* is **not** the code that the thread executes, but rather an entity that manages the execution of that code.

Comment: +1 @David.  Much cleaner solution, IMO.  Even Java doesn't recommend extending `Thread`, unless you *have* to for some freakish reason.  Which, not so oddly, i've never had to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may write your `Thread` class as a template accepting any class with `operator()`, which is called accordingly when `Thread::run()` is called. The code below shows the idea. Make changes if necessary.

```
template<typename T>
class MyThread
{
    T & _obj;
    MyThread() = delete;
    MyThread(T& o) : _obj(o) {}
    void run() 
    {
        _obj();
    }
    // other member functions
};

struct B {
    int data_to_process;
    void operator()() {
        // do something with data
    }
}

// usage
B b;
MyThread<B> t(b);
t.run();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have an implementation which mimics this, with the "Runnable" interface,and a static Thread::Run(Runnable&) as @David  suggests. I wanted to switch to the Subclass:public Thread solution for avoiding the need to create two objects every time, but if no other solution exists, I will stick with this older implementation, thank you!

Comment: @user2k5: I've never seen that syntax used before to declare a constructor.  What does it mean, exactly?

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera: there is no reason to switch from one functioning design to a worse design :)

Comment: #cHao: it's a c++11 feature. If you (mistakenly) declare `MyThread t;` without any object passed, the compiler should give you error.

Comment: @user2k5: Just because you do have another constructor the `MyThread() = delete` is unneeded. The presence of the `MyThread(T&)` constructor inhibits the implicit declaration of the default constructor. Also note that the code is incorrect, in the use, it should be `MyTread<B> t(b);` (the code is missing the template argument). Finally, if you have a C++11 compiler (use of the `= delete` feature), why would you write a thread yourself and not use the one in the language? [Final note: re. your last comment: `MyThread t()` declares a function, search for *vexing-parse*]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: for the `delete`, I just want to ensure object is always passed to the thread, and you're certainly right about the `MyThread<B>`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the reason is if your API provide some class SC:public Thread the users can do 
  SC sc; sc.start();
while if I provide a SC:public Runnable they need to 
  SC sc; Runner r(sc); r.start();
I.e. they need to create two objects every time

Comment: @user2k5: You missed my point. As soon as you add a user defined constructor, the default constructor will not be generated. Try removing the deleted destructor from the code altogether and you will see that you cannot create a `MyTread` without passing an argument (the presence of the `MyThread(T&)` constructor *removes* the default constructor, so there is no need to delete it manually). Additionally what it does not suppress is the *copy-constructor* which you most probably want deleted (as well as the assignment operator)

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera: Just saying... boost thread library has been designed and reviewed by people that know more than both you and me, and they went of the `Runnable` type of interface. The standard committee in the language has also taken the same approach (to a big extent because boost did so, given that they basically incorporated boost::thread into the standard with some modifications). Java recommends the use of `Runnable` rather than directly `Thread`. C# `Thread` is sealed and follows the same design

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use a virtual destructor with the base class calling join.

E.g.

```
class Thread{
public:
  virtual void run()=0;
  void start();
  void join();

protected:
  virtual ~Thread() 
  {
     join( ); 
  }
};
```

Comment: no, because in that way the base class deconst is called last, i.e. when B::x is already gone

Comment: Might be worth updating your question to explain this